# how to use square gateway in google pay in react using google-pay/button-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment-gateway, square, google-pay

I am not able to use square gateway in GooglePayButton in react to get the source id from the square gateway can someone please guide me how to use the square gateway and is it possible to implement the payment in GooglePayButton  without any gateway

implementation of square gateway in googlepay in react using  google-pay/button-react package

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-react-zrvkzl

Make sure to use your Square `gatewayMerchantId`.

Yes it is possible to integrate Google Pay without a gateway. However, in almost all cases you want to go with a gateway. With a [direct integration](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#direct) you need to decrypt the Google Pay payload on your server. This would expose you to a higher PCI DSS scope (Level 1 compliant) and other requirements.